# Electron Preload a function instead of an external file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, electron

I don't think this is possible, but I can't find any clear documentation saying it is not.

The `preload` feature I'm referring to is referenced here in the docs: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window

Comment: I think the bit of the documentation that states "`preload` String (optional) - Specifies a script that will be loaded before other scripts run in the page.... The value should be the absolute file path to the script." makes it pretty clear that it has to be a file, and thus can't be a function.

Comment: Ah well, I've had absolutely no luck loading a file, so I figured I'd ask here. There's no meaningful question I could ask to ascertain why loading the file isn't working, since I've got the path right, but it seems to have no effect.

Comment: Well you could just post the code that loads the file and any relevant errors you get...

Comment: No errors at all or I certainly would. The code is as straight forward as every example on the web. It's going to take some digging on my end to find enough details to ask a meaningful question in that line. Thanks very much for your replies though.

Comment: @Slbox were you ever able to find a solution? Similarly, I have not been able to get a file working for the preload script

Comment: @JackCollins it's not possible for security reasons. The file path you provide needs to be absolute, not relative. That could be your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. It should be file, as internally Electron reads file and execute it.

Comment: Figured as much. Thanks for replying.